# Create Exclude Filter on Google Analytics for Network Domain

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-spam

New to Google Analytics....  I am trying to create a filter on my Google Analytics account, for incoming traffic, with the "Network Domain" equal to: "ertelecom.ru" and "clodo.ru" and some other domains...

I cant seem to find "Network Domain" in the available segments to choose from. I have tried to create a custom exclude filter also...  What am I missing?

**EDIT:** tried to exclude on ISP domain and I am getting verification of hundreds of visits from those two sources for the "before" yet the "after" just shows blanks.

[image: **Screen Shot of Filter Verification**]

Answer (score 2):

Use "ISP Domain" in an Exclude filter.

Comment: I gave that a try using a new view and will have to wait until I receive ghost spam that meets the criteria to see if it works...  Thank you for replying!  Will accept if this works out...

Comment: Didnt work.  Still getting visits from "ertelecom.ru" and "clodo.ru"...  Verify shows hundreds of "before" sessions but the "after" sessions, etc are all blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Advanced > Conditions

Look under "Users"

Network Domain

Make sure top section set to Exclude

[image: Screenshot of Google Analytics]

Answer (score 0):

After has to be blank because it shows the number of visits that you will receive upon applying the filters.